# selecting text() using ancestor-or-self with multiple expressions XSLT XPATH

Tags: xslt, xpath, ancestor

Given the XML:

```
<surmat>
  <unpack>
     <proc>
        <para>SERVICE UPON RECEIPT</para>
     </proc>
     <proc>
         <title></title>
         <para>Lift and remove</para>
     </proc>
   </unpack>
<surmat>
```

`<surmat>` has three children `unpack | chkeqp | processeqp` so the xml could also be

```
<surmat>
  <processeqp>
     <proc>
        <para>SERVICE UPON RECEIPT</para>
     </proc>
     <proc>
         <title></title>
         <para>Lift and remove</para>
     </proc>
   </processeqp>
<surmat>
```

or

```
<surmat>
      <chkeqp>
         <title>SERVICE UPON RECEIPT</title>
         <proc>
             <title></title>
             <para>Lift and remove</para>
         </proc>
       </chkeqp>
    <surmat>
```

Using XPATH or XSLT 2.0 I simply want to check for the existence of `SERVICE UPON RECEIPT`in the first child of `<unpack>`, `<chkeqp>` or `<processeqp>` from the `<title>` template and the `<unpack/chkeqp/processeqp>` templates because `<title>` is optional. (I have to insert SERVICE... and/or the title tag if either are missing.) The children of `chkeqp` are different from `unpack` and `processeqp`.

This will return `true` as expected:

`contains(upper-case(ancestor-or-self::*[unpack or chkeqp or processeqp]),'SERVICE UPON RECEIPT')`

but I only need to check the first child and I couldn't figure out the syntax using text().

i.e. this didn't work:

`contains(upper-case(ancestor-or-self::*[unpack or chkeqp or processeqp]/text()[1]),'SERVICE UPON RECEIPT')`

or variations of this:

`contains(upper-case(ancestor-or-self::*[unpack or chkeqp or processeqp]/proc/para/text()[1]),'SERVICE UPON RECEIPT')`

If there is a more efficient way of doing this, I would appreciate you sharing it! Thanks.

This answer solved my problem:

```
contains(upper-case(ancestor-or-self::*[(self::unpack or self::chkeqp or self::processeqp) and count(preceding-sibling::*[self::unpack or self::chkeqp or self::processeqp])=0]/descendant-or-self::para[1]),'SERVICE UPON RECEIPT')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the ancestor element is the first child element of `surmat` you can count the `preceding-sibling`s:

```
contains(upper-case(ancestor-or-self::*[(self::unpack or self::chkeqp or self::processeqp) and count(preceding-sibling::*[self::unpack or self::chkeqp or self::processeqp])=0]/descendant-or-self::para[1]),'SERVICE UPON RECEIPT')
```

This expression only returns `true` for text matching the first `para` element which is a descendant of the ancestor `unpack`,`chkeqp` or `processeqp` element of the `title` element.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but given your xml, the following xpath

```
contains(upper-case(//ancestor-or-self::*[name()=('unpack','chkeqp', 'processeqp')]/*[1]//para/text()),'SERVICE UPON RECEIPT')
```

returns

> true

Is that what you are after?

Comment: I think so, thank you, I will be testing this on Tuesday. I didn't want to use `para` because the tags for `chkeqp` might not have a `para` at that same position.